# Code only outputting the same thing, wont use the .equals to output differently

Tags: java

I'm doing a project for a class I'm in and the assignment is to make a program in `Netbeans` that will take 3 inputs,

1. the person height,
2. back problems
3. heart problems.

The teacher said to use boolean for the two problems. he wants us to use `inputBack.equals("N")` to see if it equals `N` for the input which I get, anyways I'll put my code below if someone could help me out that would be great!

Basically the program only outputs different when I change the height but I need it to show something else when `b` or `h` is `Y`.

```java
double H;

String b, h;
b = back.getText();
h = heart.getText();

H = Double.parseDouble(height.getText());

if (h.equals("Y") || b.equals("Y")) {
    output.setText("Sorry, its not safe for you to ride the coaster");
}

if ((H >= 122 && H <= 188) && (h.equals("N") || b.equals("N"))) {
    output.setText("You are cleared to ride, have fun!");
} else if (b.equals("Y") || h.equals("Y")) {
    output.setText("Sorry, its not safe for you to ride the coaster");
} else {
    output.setText("Sorry, its not safe for you to ride the coaster");
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the values for 'b' and 'h' are actually the values you are expecting? If you are working in something like netbeans, your first step when diagnosing an issue like this should be to use the debugger to step through the code and check your variables and logic.

Comment: Your first condition is: "either b or h is Y". But you don't stop there. You continue to the next condition, which is "if the height is... and either b or h is N". Is this the logic you wanted? Go through it with a debugger or pen and paper and see if it does what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it too complex actually. Your real issue is in the line:

```
if ((H >= 122 && H <= 188) && (h.equals("N") || b.equals("N")))
```

The OR operator should be an AND operator there. If the person has no heart issues, your test will always succeed no matter the value of `b`. This is why your output won't change even if you change the value.

I think a simple solution like the one below would already be sufficient to achieve what you want:

```
// Please use sensible names for your variables, and no uppercase single letters
double height = Double.parseDouble(heightField.getText()); // This could throw a NumberFormatException, you probably want to catch it
String backIssues = backField.getText();
String heartIssues = heartField.getText();

// Drop your first if test, it is completely unnecessary there.

// If the person is between 122 and 188 cm, and has no heart issues and has no back issues: Hooray!
if (height >= 122 && height <= 188 && heartIssues.equalsIgnoreCase("N") && backIssues.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
  output.setText("You are cleared to ride, have fun!");
} else { // In all other cases, not allowed to ride the coaster
  output.setText("Sorry, its not safe for you to ride the coaster");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! also my variable names are quite easy to type out and it just makes the coding faster, also it's not hard to remember which one is which so this is just my own way of making things easier I guess. oh well.

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah, it's a normal reflex and understandable for a small personal project. But as your project grows and gets more complex, it will be harder to remember all variables + sooner or later people with less context will probably also get to read your code (like us on Stackoverlow). It's just a good habit to take a bit more time and write readable, maintainable code, it could save you a lot of trouble in the future... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have too many redundant if/else statements. You can simplify your code like this:

```
//Heart or back problem, so no riding
if (h.equals("Y") || b.equals("Y")) {
    output.setText("Sorry, its not safe for you to ride the coaster");
}
else {  //health ok, check height

  if (H >= 122 && H <= 188)
      output.setText("You are cleared to ride, have fun!");
  else
      output.setText("You are outside the height requirements, you can't ride")
}
```

Also keep in mind if the user puts in a value for height that is not numeric you will get an exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

your error is on this line :

```
if ((H >= 122 && H <= 188) && (h.equals("N") || b.equals("N"))) {
```

Indeed if your height is fine, you can go to the coaster even if you have one of the two others problem. 
If you put h="N" and b="Y" the condition `h.equals("N") || b.equals("N")` will be true because h="N".
The good thing to do is to replace this line by :

```
if ((H >= 122 && H <= 188) && (h.equals("N") && b.equals("N"))) {
```

You can also simplify your code, you put too many if...